# Use filter to find sub-element of table in database (DBeaver)

Tags: postgresql, filter, schema, dbeaver

I'm currently trying to list all Triggers available in a PostgreSQL database, regardless of the tables, using the DBeaver GUI.

What I would like to get looks like this:

https://ibb.co/dJZXCo

A result displaying only the Triggers category would be enough, I just want to quickly identify where the triggers are in my base.

To do so, I've tried to use global filters on the base itself, but it only filters table names.

I don't know if I can configure search depth so it includes inner elements of tables; or if there is a dedicated syntax to process the Triggers category in tables; or if the solution doesn't have anything to do with filtering.

There might be a very simple solution, but I can't seem to find it.

Thank you!

Comment: `select * from pg_trigger`?

Comment: Is it possible to do that in the DBeaver GUI directly? (sorry, I'm a super novice with this tool). By the way, I noticed I didn't mention DBeaver in my post besides the tags, I'll update it.

Comment: @Ralph if your DBeaver GUI is connected to your database the select should work fine.

Comment: I tried and it works as expected. It doesn't give me a clean output in the navigation panel though, but it'll do. Thanks!